# Why does this C# floating point comparison fail only in 32 bit?

Tags: c#, floating-point

I am having very different results when comparing, what seems like identical floating point comparison statements. What is bizarre, both statements are true in 64-bit, and only in 32-bit are the results not equal.

Even if I explicitly cast the '132' and/or 'initial' to an Int32, the result in 32-bit is still the same.

```
int initial = 134;
float initialConverted = initial/255.0f;

// both are true in 64, abs2 is false in 32
var abs = Math.Abs(initialConverted - (134/255.0f)) < float.Epsilon;
var abs2 = Math.Abs(initialConverted - (initial/255.0f)) < float.Epsilon;
```

Why is there a problem with division when the integer value is stored in its own field?

Comment: `float.Epsilon` is NOT the right value to use for these kinds of comparisons. Make up your own epsilon which is appropriate for the context in which you are using it. `float.Epsilon` represents *"the smallest positive Single value that is significant in numeric operations or comparisons when the value of the Single instance is zero."* - this is a FAR bigger value that the rounding errors you are likely to encounter when using floats.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: actually, that would imply epsilon is far smaller than would be useful (note the definition of epsilon in C# is very different than in other languages).

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't do that kind of comparison at all- instead of comparing x/255.0 to y, compare x to y*255.0f, you're far less likely to run into rounding errors. You possibly don't even need to use floats at all by doing it that way.

Comment: What I submitted was the smallest piece of code that produces the error. The actual code is a color converter than converts colors with a byte per channel into a triplet of floats scaled from 0 to 1.

Comment: @SimonByrne The italicised text in my comment is from the C# documentation. And indeed, `float.Epsilon` IS far smaller than is useful. However also note in my comment I accidentally wrote "this is a FAR bigger value that the rounding errors " when I meant to write "this is a FAR *smaller* value that the rounding errors", but I think everyone got what I meant. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here.

Firstly, C# uses a different definition of epsilon than other languages. [`float.Epsilon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.epsilon(v=vs.110).aspx) is the next largest `float` after 0. Due to the scaling property of floating point numbers, this is very small (`1.0e-45f` assuming standard IEEE754 binary32 format). In most other languages (such as say, [`FLT_EPSILON` in C](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfloat/)), epsilon refers to the difference between 1 and the next largest `float` (`1.1920929e-7f` in binary32 format).

What this means is that the threshold you're using is *very* tight, too tight too allow for the usual floating point rounding error.

The reason for the difference between archiectures is due to differences in handling *intermediate precision*. On a modern CPU, there are two sets of instructions for handling floating point numbers:

- x87 instructions: these date back to the original 8086 processors (or, more specifically, the 8087 coprocessors that accompanied them). They internally utilise a higher precision than the format, namely an 80-bit format (compared with typical 32-bit floats and 64-bit doubles). However at certain steps, operations will need to be truncated to the destination format. The precise rules for when this occurs depends on the language (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx) for C#). This is the reason why your `abs2` is false on a 32-bit machine: `initialConverted` has been rounded to a `float`, but the second `(initial/255.0f)` has not (I'm not sure why this doesn't occur in `abs`, but I guess the compiler optimises away the constant expression `(134/255.0f)` into a `float`).
- SSE instructions: these were introduced as "fast-but-restrictive" floating point operations for games and multimedia, but now have almost completely supplanted the x87 instructions on modern processors. Unlike x87, there is no extended precision (so a `float` - `float` immediately returns a `float`), they are faster, and offer basic parallelism via SIMD operations. They are almost certainly being used on a 64-bit machine (they are also available on most 32-bit machines from the past decade, but compilers tend not to use them, I guess for compatibility reasons). As there is no extended precision, `initialConverted` and `(initial/255.0f)` will both be identical `float`s, hence `abs2` is true.

Comment: I can confirm that the assembly uses SSE instructions in (and only in) 64-bit. I was wondering the significance of this; now I know. The intermediate precision was what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is just a variant of the normal floating point comparison and accuracy problems.

Floating point calculations are *slightly* different in 32-bit and 64-bit and *slightly* different between DEBUG and RELEASE builds. Most likely in one setting it evaluates to 0, in another to something equal to or slightly larger than `float.Epsilon`.

I would not use `float.Epsilon`, it is *far* too small to handle normal inaccuracies. Instead you need to decide on an epsilon value yourself, that would be "close enough".

`float.Epsilon` is the same as `Single.Epsilon`, which is documented as:

> Represents the smallest positive Single value that is greater than zero. This field is constant.

In other words, this is just the smallest number representable in the Single data type, it is not usable to handle inaccuracies in calculations, you need something larger for that. `Single.Epsilon` is somewhere in the vicinity of 1.4E-45 which doesn't allow any inaccuracies at all.

Comment: I understand the accuracy problems normally. And yes, the Math.Abs() doesn't evaluate to 0.0 in the cases where it's false. But in this scenario, the mere fact of storing the value in a field shouldn't introduce a consistent issue. Or am I wrong with this assumption?

Comment: The cpu may work with slightly different precision from the storage types as well. You're operating on such very very very slightly different values that this is within the documented expectations. If you need a definite absolute informative explanation on *why* the values ended up as they did you need to read the compiler source code, the JITter source code, read up on CPU and FPU technology and so on.